# Does 20.10 version of ubuntu works with secure boot enabled?

Tags: 20.10

I have an HP PC in which I have installed Windows 10 and would like to also install ubuntu in dual boot but will it work with secure boot in UEFI or I will need to disable secure boot to run ubuntu?

Comment: I'm involved with Lubuntu QA-testing, and we test for BIOS, uEFI & Secure UEFI, in combinations of encrypted/unencrypted, internet/no-internet, full disk, install alongside, replace  partition, custom partitioning with separate /home, btfs, xfs, language etc...   The answer is YES, however some devices still have unusual setups that can be outside of what is tested.

Comment: Agreed with above. You can do it. After the install you may need Boot-Repair.  But it can be done.  BUT certain BIOS setups can make it painful.